# NET::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED from react-native-webview in Android

Tags: android, react-native, webview, android-webview, react-native-webview

We are using a `WebView` from `react-native-webview` in our app to show a preview of an email. The preview itself is a HTML file that is located in the repo, so we are requiring it and passing it to the WebView component like so:

```
  const emailHtml = require('./ConfirmationEmailPreview.html');

  <WebView
    source={emailHtml}
    //Other props
  />
```

However, on Android the HTML is not rednered and instead the following error message is displayed: NET::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED. I understand that this is a security feature but don't understand why it is triggered for a local file. I have seen some advice online (see [here](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/net-err_cleartext_not_permitted/)) on how to resolve this issue, but the suggestions either seem to come with security risks or require the HTML to come from a domain.

Is there a way to prevent this from causing an error WITHOUT adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic=”true”` to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file? I want to avoid this as Google advises against permitting cleartext due to security issues.

Comment: So the file is static? If yes, make it an asset on Android.  https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/load-local-content

Comment: @Robert so currently this HTML is being required from inside a React Native TS component - I'm not super familiar with the Android development side of things, is there a way to make it an asset on Android but still be able to pass it as a prop to the `WebView` component?

Comment: Alternatively you can allow clear text traffic for one domain only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77537614/150978 But in the end it would be better to switch to https. You have not mentioned it in your question what server does provide this html file?

Comment: @Robert as mentioned in my post, the HTML isn't hosted on a domain/provided by a server. The HTML comes from a local, static file that is in the same repo as the rest of the frontend of the React native project